# How to fix multi-valued function on contour?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, integration

I am sorry to ask such an embarrassingly simple question here. My question is about  contour integral of the multivalude function.
I want to calculate the Fourier transformation of a muti-valued function $f$
$$G(\omega,\mathbf{k})=\int dt d^{d-1}\mathbf{x} f(t,\mathbf{x})
e^{i\omega t-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}$$
with condition that 
$$\omega>0,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\omega^2-\mathbf{k}^2>0$$
so that we can deform the contour from the green one to the red one.
Function $f$ is given by
$$ f(t,\mathbf{x})=
 \big(\frac{-1}{t^2-\mathbf{x}^2-i\epsilon t}\big)^\Delta
$$
For $t<0$, $f$ can be written as
$$ f(t,\mathbf{x})=
\frac{e^{i\pi \Delta}}{ \big(t^2-x^2\big)^\Delta}
$$

For $t>0$, $f$ can be written as
$$ f(t,\mathbf{x})=
\frac{e^{-i\pi \Delta}}{ \big(t^2-x^2\big)^\Delta}
$$

So I need to write down the function on the four legs, $1,2,3,4$ as shown in the figure. My question is how to fied the multi-valued function on each contour? Thanks for any suggestions in advance.
[image]